# Integrating factor for differential equation gamma function

Tags: integration, gamma-function

Given the following differential equation
\begin{equation}
\left(\theta + \frac{1}{1-z}\right)g(z) -\frac{dg}{dz} = \frac{z^\theta}{1-z}
\end{equation}
It is known that $(1-z)e^{-\theta z}$ is an integrating factor (how?). Given this, and that $g(1)=1$ we "readily determine" (how?) that 
\begin{align}
g(z) &= \frac{e^{\theta z}}{1-z}\int^1_z t^\theta e^{-\theta t}dt\\
& = \frac{e^{\theta z}}{1-z}\theta^{-(\theta+1)}[\Gamma(\theta+1,\theta z)-\Gamma(\theta+1,\theta)]
\end{align}

Any help or comments appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integrating factor:
$$\exp\left(-\int \left( \theta + \frac 1 {1-z} \right) \ \mathrm dz\right) = \exp \left( -z\theta + \ln(1-z) \right) = (1-z)e^{-\theta z}$$

In general, the integrating factor of $\dfrac {\mathrm dg} {\mathrm dz} + p(z) g = q(z)$ is $\displaystyle \exp \left( \int p(z) \ \mathrm dz \right)$.

---

Then our differential equation transforms to:
$$\frac {\mathrm d} {\mathrm dz} \left(g (1-z)e^{-\theta z}\right) = -\frac {z^\theta} {1-z} (1-z)e^{-\theta z}$$

which simplies to the form required.